# gRPC protobuffers Java cannot set CallOptions for BlockingStub

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a simple proto file, to create my java classes

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "some.project.grpc";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message PingRequest { }
message PingResponse { }

service MyServer {
    rpc Ping(PingRequest) returns (PingResponse);
}
```

With gradle and the google protobuf plugin (https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) I create my classes with

```
gradle generateProto
```

The generated `MyServerGrpc` has an internal class `MyServerBlockingStub` that has two constructors:

```
private MyServerBlockingStub(io.grpc.Channel channel) { ... }
private MyServerBlockingStub(io.grpc.Channel channel, io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) { ... }
```

The `MyServerGrpc` class does expose the first one as `newBlockingStub(io.grpc.Channel channel)` but not the second - which I would need.

Like this, I cannot set any call options, such as timeout. I could easily manipulate the generated file to allow me access to the constructor I need, but those changes would be lost on the next generation - so it's not really an option.

Since it seems such an easy fix I was thinking:

- Am I missing some option that would expose this constructor to me?
- Is the intention to set the `CallOptions` object somewhere else that I have not found yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyServerGrpc` extends `AbstractStub`. `AbstractStub` has `with*` methods mirroring those on `CallOptions`.

So you want to do something like:

```
newBlockingStub(yourChannel).withDeadlineAfter(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.